# ng2Table examples break after upgrading Angular

Tags: angular, angular2-directives

I cloned the ng data table examples at https://github.com/ggmod/angular-2-data-table-demo

Everything works great until i try to update packages in package.json to later versions. The app will no longer compile.

is there a solution to this?

Comment: Please show us some errors or something that will help us better understand your issue - which packages, what errors?

Answer (score 0):

I followed the following steps to get the Angular2 Data Table Demos to work with Angular 4:

1. Cloned the repository found at https://github.com/ggmod/angular-2-data-table-demo
2. Created a brand new Angular 4 project using CLI..
   install -g angular-cli
   ng new demo
3. copied the demo folders found in the demo project into my new project
4. ran npm i angular-4-data-table --save  to get the necessary prerequisites for my new project
5. Imported DataTable Module and the demo components into app.module..

```js
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { DataTableDemo1 } from './demo1/data-table-demo1'
import {  DataTableDemo3 } from './demo3/data-table-demo3'
import { DataTableModule } from 'angular-4-data-table';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
  DataTableDemo1,
  DataTableDemo3,
    FooComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    DataTableModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

6. Update the import statements in each of the demo components as follows..

```js
import { DataTable, DataTableTranslations, DataTableResource } from 'angular-4-data-table';
```

note the only change to the demo components was to swap 'angular-2-data-table' with 'angular-4-data-table'